# extract n characters/numbers after exact pattern

Tags: r, regex

I have the following string: 123-4567-C-4321-DD.xxxx

I would like to extract only the four digits "4321" after the "C-". Note that the "C" could also be a "P", either could be upper or lower case.

I have tried many suggestions that looks like it might work, but to no avail. This seemed close, but is actually grabbing the first four numbers it finds:

```
[^c|C,p|P-]{4}
```

expected = 4321, 
actual = 4567

Comment: What about `gsub("(.*)([CP]-)(\\d{4}).*", "\\3", s, perl=TRUE)`?

Comment: Try this: `.*(?<=C-)(\d+).*`

Comment: Or in python re.findall(r'.*(?<=C-)(\d+).*', '123-4567-C-4321-DD.xxxx')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use str_match and use `(?i)` to get a case insensitive match and capture 4 digits in a group 1:

```
(?i)-[CP]-([0-9]{4})
```

[R demo](https://ideone.com/cj3sS1) | [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dna3ky/1)

For example:

```
library(stringr)
text = "123-4567-C-4321-DD.xxxx"
pattern = "(?i)-[CP]-([0-9]{})"
print(str_match(text, pattern)[,2])
```

Result

```
[1] "4321"
```

Or use a positive lookbehind:

```
pattern = "(?i)(?<=-[CP]-)[0-9]{4}"
print(str_match(text, pattern)[,1])
```

**Note**

In a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) the pipe `|` does not mean or but is a pipe literal.

If you start the character class with `^` it is negating what it is allowed to match, so your pattern `[^c|C,p|P-]{4}` matches 4 times not any of `c`, `C`, `P`, `p`, `|`, `,` or `-`

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input, but this solution worked the best, specifically the positive look behind pattern. For some reason the first solution would occasionally include the preceding "C" or "P". And thanks for explaining why my original pattern did not work right.

Comment: So I was looking at the Regex Demo that is linked above. It looks like a good tool to learn Regex, I will explore some more. But I was thinking that it would be great if there was a site the did the opposite: Input the string, or as many versions as needed; highlight the pattern of interest; and then say if you want to extract, remove, replace, etc, that pattern; and what ever other modifiers needed. Then the site would generate the regex code for whatever language you need. Anyone ever hear of someplace like that?

Answer (score 3):

This will work.

```
(?<=[(C|c|P|p)]-)([0-9]){4}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one.

```
gsub("(.*)([cCpP]-)(\\d{4}).*", "\\3", s, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "4321" "4321" "4321" "4321"
```

***Data***

```
s <- c("123-4567-C-4321-DD.xxxxA", "123-4567-P-4321-DD.xxxxA", 
       "123-4567-c-4321-DD.xxxxA", "123-4567-p-4321-DD.xxxxA")
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's in fix position you can count backwards (and forward) with `stringr::str_sub()` or only forward with base R `substr()`.

```
stringr::str_sub(s, -13, -10)
```

Base R:

```
substr(s, 12, 15)
```

Output:

```
[1] "4321" "4321" "4321" "4321"
```

Using @jay.sf's dataset:

```
s <- c("123-4567-C-4321-DD.xxxxA", "123-4567-P-4321-DD.xxxxA", 
       "123-4567-c-4321-DD.xxxxA", "123-4567-p-4321-DD.xxxxA")
```

Answer (score 0):

I used str_match function in stringr package.

```
pattern = "-[c|C|p|P]-(\\d{4})"
str_match(text, pattern)
```

There parenthese make a group.

So you can export digits that you want to get using a group.

[Code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgOWV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-regex approach,

```
sapply(strsplit(s, '-', fixed = TRUE), function(i)i[which(i %in% c('C', 'c', 'p', 'P')) + 1])
#[1] "4321" "4321" "4321" "4321"
```

**DATA** (taken from @jay.sf)

```
s <- c("123-4567-C-4321-DD.xxxxA", "123-4567-P-4321-DD.xxxxA", 
       "123-4567-c-4321-DD.xxxxA", "123-4567-p-4321-DD.xxxxA")
```